# How can I add customised choice fields in django (2.1)?

Tags: django, list

This is the model class that stores the details about an app. In this model is it possible to add a customised list fields. i,e a user should be able to define a set of choices and later it will be available for adding (as tags) to the builds of the app.

```
class App(models.Model):
   bundle_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Build(models.Model):
   app = models.ForeignKey(App, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   uploaded_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right you want to do create a new model `Tag` with `builds` attribute:

```py
    class Tag(models.Model):
       ...
       builds = models.ManyToManyField(Build, related_name="tags")
```

Then you can assign multiple tags to one build and vice versa multiple builds to one tag.

You can read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField

Comment: Thanks for replying. Also I need to have a customised list of tags corresponding to an app, from that list the builds are assigned with the required tags. While defining it as a manytomany field [Tag-Build] Is it possible to relate with the app model?

Comment: then i would add another row `apps - models.ManyToManyField` to your `Tag` model. There would be saved the information to which apps is the tag assignable.